# prove that : $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b} + \frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+ \frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a} \geq 3$

Tags: inequality

> For $a^2+b^2+c^2 =3$, with $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b} + \frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+ \frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a} \geq 3.$$

Can any one help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: i've tried several way but sadly i don't think any of them is the right direction.

Comment: This probably also needs the condition $a,b,c\ge0$ (otherwise say let $a=b=c=-1$ and you disprove it).

Comment: absolutely,I forgot to mention that,my bad.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716949/prove-that-fraca2a-b-fracb2b-c-fracc2c-a-ge-frac/718084#718084) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying both LHS and RHS by $a+b+c = s > 0$, you have:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\cdot (a+b) \right)+ \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\cdot c \right) \ge 3(a+b+c) $$
$$\iff 6+ \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\cdot c \right) \ge 3s $$

Now note that $a^2+b^2 \ge \frac12(a+b)^2$ using AM-GM, so it is enough to show that
$$6 + \frac12\sum_{cyc}(s-c)c \ge 3s \iff 6 + \frac{s^2}2-\frac32 \ge 3s \iff (s-3)^2\ge 0$$

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks. Not sure if the trick works elsewhere, but quite satisfying here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(c^2+ab+ac+bc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq3\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(c^2+3v^2)}{9uv^2-w^3}\geq3\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}$$ or
$$\frac{2(9v^4-6uw^3)+6v^2(9u^2-6v^2)}{9uv^2-w^3}\geq3\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}$$ or
$$2(9u^2v^2-3v^4-2uw^3)\geq(9uv^2-w^3)\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}$$ or
$$ 2(9u^2v^2-3v^4)-9uv^2\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}\geq(4u-\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2})w^3$$
and since $4u-\sqrt{3u^2-2v^2}>0$ it's enough to prove our inequality

for a maximal value of $w^3$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$ is homogeneous, we can assume $b=c=1$, which gives
$$\frac{2(a^2+1)}{a+1}+1\geq\sqrt{3(a^2+2)}$$ or
$$(a-1)^2(a^2+3)\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Applying AM-GM, we get:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a+b} + \dfrac{a^2 + c^2}{a+c} + \dfrac{c^2 + b^2}{c+b}}{3} \geq \Bigg( \Bigg(\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a+b} \Bigg) \Bigg(\dfrac{a^2 + c^2}{a+c} \Bigg) \Bigg(\dfrac{c^2 + b^2}{c+b} \Bigg)\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$\geq \Bigg( \Bigg(\dfrac{a+ b}{2} \Bigg) \Bigg(\dfrac{a+ c}{2} \Bigg) \Bigg(\dfrac{c + b}{2} \Bigg)\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

(Follows from AM-GM again.)

$\geq \frac{1}{2} ((a+b)(b+c)(a+c))^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$\geq \frac{1}{2} ((a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) -abc)^{\frac{1}{3}} \quad \ldots (1)$

Clearly $(abc)_{max} = \bigg( \dfrac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{3}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 1$

Now by Lagrange's method of undetermined multipliers it isn't hard to show that subject to the constraint $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 = 3$, the maximum values of $a+b+c$ and $ab +bc +ca$ are both 3.

Together we get:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a+b} + \dfrac{a^2 + c^2}{a+c} + \dfrac{c^2 + b^2}{c+b}}{3} \geq \dfrac{1}{2}((3 \times 3) -1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

And the required inequality follows.